# How to update a generic type with MongoDB C# driver in MongoDB 2.7

Tags: c#, mongodb

Following code from this question [How to update a generic type with MongoDB C# driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727612/how-to-update-a-generic-type-with-mongodb-c-sharp-driver) no longer works, how to do the same in MongoDB 2.7?

```
void Update(T entity)
{
    collection.Save<T>(entity);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `Save` is only available in legacy MongoDB C# driver. You can find unresolved ticket with discussion on [driver JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1560).

It's still possible to implement something similar in C#. The behavior is documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/):

> If the document does not contain an _id field, then the save() method calls the insert() method. During the operation, the mongo shell will create an ObjectId and assign it to the _id field.

and

> If the document contains an _id field, then the save() method is equivalent to an update with the upsert option set to true and the query predicate on the _id field.

So you can introduce marker interface in C# to represent `_id` field:

```
public interface IIdentity
{
    ObjectId Id { get; set; }
}
```

and then you can implement `Save` like this:

```
public void Update<T>(T entity) where T : IIdentity
{
    if(entity.Id == ObjectId.Empty)
    {
        collection.InsertOne(entity); // driver creates _id under the hood
    }
    else
    {
        collection.ReplaceOne(x => x.Id == entity.Id, entity, new UpdateOptions() { IsUpsert = true } );
    }
}
```

or simpler:

```
public void Update<T>(T entity) where T : IIdentity
{
    if(entity.Id == ObjectId.Empty)
    {
        entity.Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
    }
    collection.ReplaceOne(x => x.Id == entity.Id, entity, new UpdateOptions() { IsUpsert = true } );
}
```

Comment: I don't think the `entity.Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();` is required, is it?

Comment: @dnickless yes, it's not necessary, I just wanted to follow the description