# Document Update Using Driver Ignoring _id

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'd like to be able to update a key/value pair within a Document in a Collection without regard to the _id. This [SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52634722/how-to-update-a-generic-type-with-mongodb-c-sharp-driver-in-mongodb-2-7) appears to provide a way to do what I want, but it requires a focus on the _id key.

Essentially, what can I do to get my code, as shown below, to work without adding the `[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]` attribute to the class?

Based on the code which I'll show below, I think I'm close, and I *do* have a possible workaround, using the attribute, which I'll also show. However, I'd like to do this without decorating the classes with any attributes if possible.

Why no _id? Personally, I find the _id field just gets in the way. It's not part of any of my classes, and MongoDB isn't relational, so I simply don't use it. I freely admit that I may be completely missing the intent and idea behind the use of the _id field, but I simply don't see a need for it in MongoDB. Nevertheless, if possible, I'd like to focus on working without a focus on the _id field.

With that said, I have methods for retrieving a single document or an entire collection along with inserting a single document or entire collection, generically, without regard to the _id field.

I found that the key to ignoring the _id in a "select" is to use a Projection. I'm not all that familiar with the driver, but here are the lines of code that do the magic:

```
public const string ELEMENT_ID = "_id";
ProjectionDefinition<T> projection = Builders<T>.Projection.Exclude(ELEMENT_ID);
IFindFluent<T, T> found = mongoCollection.Find(bsonDocument).Project<T>(projection);
```

For background info, here is a retrieval method, ignoring _id:

```
public T GetSingle<T>(string property, string value) where T : class, new()
        {
            T tObject = null;
            try
            {
                if (MongoContext.MongoClient != null && MongoContext.MongoDatabase != null)
                {
                    string className = typeof(T).ToString();
                    int lastPeriod = className.LastIndexOf('.');
                    int length = className.Length - lastPeriod;
                    className = className.Substring(lastPeriod + 1, length - 1);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(className))
                    {
                        IMongoCollection<T> mongoCollection = MongoContext.MongoDatabase.GetCollection<T>(className);
                        if (mongoCollection != null)
                        {
                            BsonDocument bsonDocument = new BsonDocument();
                            ProjectionDefinition<T> projection = Builders<T>.Projection.Exclude(ELEMENT_ID);
                            PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
                            if (propertyInfo != null && propertyInfo.Length > 0)
                            {
                                IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> piExisting = propertyInfo.Where(pi => pi.Name.Equals(property, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
                                if (piExisting != null && piExisting.Any())
                                {
                                    BsonValue bsonValue = BsonValue.Create(value);
                                    BsonElement bsonElement = new BsonElement(property, bsonValue);
                                    if (bsonElement != null)
                                    {
                                        bsonDocument.Add(bsonElement);
                                    }
                                    IFindFluent<T, T> found = mongoCollection.Find(bsonDocument).Project<T>(projection);
                                    if (found != null)
                                    {
                                        tObject = found.FirstOrDefault<T>();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.WriteToLog(Logger.LoggerMessage(ex));
            }
            return tObject;
        }
```

Similar to other another [SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30257013/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-2-0-update-document), I've tried to use `FindOneAndUpdate`, but I receive the following error:

> Element '_id' does not match any field or property of class
>   ClassThingy.Suffix.

If I could apply the Projection to the `FindOneAndUpdate` somehow, I think that might resolve my issue, but I'm not able to find a way to do that application.

Here is my code:

```
public T UpdateSingle<T>(T item, string property, object originalValue, object newValue) where T : class, new()
{
    string className = string.Empty;
    T updatedDocument = null;
    try
    {
        if (MongoContext.MongoClient != null && MongoContext.MongoDatabase != null)
        {
            className = ClassUtility.GetClassNameFromObject<T>(item);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(className))
            {
                IMongoCollection<T> mongoCollection = MongoContext.MongoDatabase.GetCollection<T>(className);
                if (mongoCollection != null)
                {
                    BsonDocument bsonDocument = new BsonDocument();
                    ProjectionDefinition<T> projection = Builders<T>.Projection.Exclude(ELEMENT_ID);
                    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
                    if (propertyInfo != null && propertyInfo.Length > 0)
                    {
                        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> piExisting = propertyInfo.Where(pi => pi.Name.Equals(property, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
                        if (piExisting != null && piExisting.Any())
                        {
                            BsonValue bsonValue = BsonValue.Create(originalValue);
                            BsonElement bsonElement = new BsonElement(property, bsonValue);
                            if (bsonElement != null)
                            {
                                bsonDocument.Add(bsonElement);
                            }
                            IFindFluent<T, T> found = mongoCollection.Find(bsonDocument).Project<T>(projection);
                            if (found != null)
                            {
                                FilterDefinition<T> filterDefinition = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(property, originalValue);
                                UpdateDefinition<T> updateDefinition = Builders<T>.Update.Set(property, newValue);
                                updatedDocument = mongoCollection.FindOneAndUpdate<T>(filterDefinition, updateDefinition);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.WriteToLog(Logger.LoggerMessage(ex));
    }
    return updatedDocument;
}
```

Interestingly enough, while the `FindOneAndUpdate` method actually appears to succeed and the "Suffix" collection does, in fact, get modified. Also, the return doesn't contain the modification. Instead, it's the "original" (when I use the workaround as shown below).

More Info:

Suffix Class:

```
public class Suffix
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

```
Suffix suffix = new Suffix();
MongoRepository.MongoRepository mongoRepository = new MongoRepository.MongoRepository("MyDataBase");
mongoRepository.UpdateSingle<Suffix>(suffix, "Description", "Jr", "Junior");
```

Workaround:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Suffix
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

But, much rather not use the attribute if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you're missing here is the third parameter of `.FindOneAndUpdate()` method which is of type `FindOneAndUpdateOptions<T,T>`. That's the place where you can define if you want to get document `After` or `Before` the modification. `Before` is the default value Moreover you can specify the projection and exclude `_id` property. Try:

```
FilterDefinition<T> filterDefinition = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(property, originalValue);
UpdateDefinition<T> updateDefinition = Builders<T>.Update.Set(property, newValue);
ProjectionDefinition<T, T> projection = Builders<T>.Projection.Exclude("_id");
var options = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<T>()
{
    Projection = projection,
    ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After
};
updatedDocument = mongoCollection.FindOneAndUpdate<T>(filterDefinition, updateDefinition, options);
```

Comment: Perfect.That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!